# ViewPager only load the fragments once time

Tags: android, pagertabstrip

I have an android `DrawerLayout` and it has 2 items, one of them is a `fragment` with a `PagerTabStrip` and it load their `fragments` but when I change the item of the `DrawerLayout` and I come back to the `PagerTabStrip` it loads the tabs, but doesn't their `fragments`.

This is my PagerTabStrip class

```
public class maintabs extends Fragment {

    FragmentPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;
    PagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip;
    View rootView;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabs_main, container, false);
        ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
        pagerTabStrip = (PagerTabStrip) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager_header);
        pagerTabStrip.setDrawFullUnderline(true);
        adapterViewPager = new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

        vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
        return  rootView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution.
Just use a FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead FragmentPagerAdapter